# What is the projective dimension of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_l[T,T^{-1}]$ ? l is a prime number 

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $l$ be a prime number, $\mathbb{Z}_l$ be the ring of $l$-adic integers, then what is the projective dimension of the ring $A:=\mathbb{Z}_l[T,T^{-1}]$?

Is it two?

Comment: What is the difference between the projective dimension of A and the projective dimension of the category of A-modules?

Comment: Don't forget the words 'continuous' and 'open' should be inserted appropriately.  As a crude ring, $\mathbb{Z}_l$ is infinitely-generated and almost certainly has infinite projective dimension, but there should be no earthly reason you want to forget the topology.

Comment: @Greg: $\mathbb Z_l$ is a principal ideal domain, so its global dimension is $1$.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for reminding me the ambiguity about proj. dim.

Comment: Heer:  I wasn't trying to remind you of anything; I was asking a question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_p$ is a principal ideal domain, so it is Noetherian and its global dimension is $1$. Now, there is a general theorem that tells you that for all right Noetherian rings $R$ one has $$\operatorname{gldim}R[X,X^{-1}]=\operatorname{gldim}R+1.$$ So your answer is indeed $2$.

You'll find that theorem proved pretty much anywhere where global dimension is discussed. For example, J. C. McConnell and J. C. Robson's bible *Noncommutative Noetherian Rings* (which should be called, as usual, "non-necesarily commutative noetherian rings"...)